# Stacking Angular Material 2 Dialogs like toasts

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using the [`@angular/material`](https://github.com/angular/material2) library and am trying to create a sort of bootstrap toast like effect. Where I want potentially multiple dialogs to appear in the top right hand corner and stack up below the most recent one.

By disabling the backdrop and closing features, I have this code:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NotificationInputComponent, {disableClose: true, hasBackdrop: false});
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.selectedOption = result;
});
```

Which works quite well, so when triggered, I get this in the middle of my screen:

[image]

If I manually change the elements css to `position: absolute; right: 10px` then it goes to the right hand side of the screen and looks correct. The issue is, now if I trigger another dialogue, I have to do the same again, but set the `top` property to stop it overlaying the existing dialog. I could presumably keep track of all the triggered dialogs in my component and manually update the top margin. But I was wondering if there is a neater way of doing it, either getting them to stack in css, or possibly is there a way to inject the triggered dialog into an [`@angular/flexbox`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) layout?

Comment: there are plenty of toast libraries for ng 2. why are you trying to make the dialogs do something they were not designed to do?

Comment: @toskv 1. Because I have to many front end libs at the moment, so I am investigating if this is an area where I can cut down on one. 2. Most of the libs don't have the features I need, to enable  a toast to collect a response (as you can see in the image) and then close the toast on submit and match it up with it's original prompt.